# ¿Como tomar el valor neto de un select en un change JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, ajax

Tengo la tabla `país` y `ciudad`, la ciudad depende del país, por lo cual decidí dinamicamente que cuando yo seleccione el país me haga un `change` tomando el `value`, en este caso el id_pais y que haga un envió por `ajax` para que me liste las ciudades que dependen de ese país...

el problema es que me esta enviando lo siguiente: `(id_pais=5)` y no me esta enviando unicamente el **5** `(que es el id del pais)`...

Agradecería el interes y la intención de poder colaborarme...

**CODIGO**

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'paises',
        type: 'POST',
    })
    .done(function(answer){
        var result= $.parseJSON(answer);

            $('#pais').append('<option disabled selected>-- Seleccione Pais -- </option>');
        for(var i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            $('#pais').append('<option value="' + result[i].id_pais + '">' + result[i].nombre_pais+ '</option>');

        }
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });

    $('#paises').change(function() {

        var id_pais= $(this).serialize();
        console.log(id_pais);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ciudades',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'id_pais' : id_pais},
        })
        .done(function(respuesta) {
            console.log(respuesta);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        })
```

Comment: ¿Para qué serializas el elemento? Solamente envía su **valor**: `var id_pais = this.value`.

Comment: Es la primera ves que hago el change creí que esa era la forma adecuada igualmente muchas gracias...Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema amigo es que estas serializando 2 veces:

```
var id_pais= $(this).serialize();
```

devuelve id_pais: 5, a lo que le estas concatenando despues:

```
{'id_pais' : id_pais}
```

con lo cual quedaría así:

```
{'id_pais' : 'id_pais: 5'}
```

Ahora tu solución estaría haciéndolo de esta manera:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'paises',
    type: 'POST',
})
.done(function(answer){
    var result= $.parseJSON(answer);

        $('#pais').append('<option disabled selected>-- Seleccione Pais -- </option>');
    for(var i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        $('#pais').append('<option value="' + result[i].id_pais + '">' + result[i].nombre_pais+ '</option>');

    }
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
});

$('#paises').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ciudades',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'id_pais' : parseInt($(this).val())},
    })
    .done(function(respuesta) {
        console.log(respuesta);
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });
```

Suerte Amigo.

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias....

Comment: @Daniel No olvides marcar esta respuesta como correcta si ayudó a resolver tu problema.